# CQRS and WebSockets

Tags: architecture, websocket, web-deployment, cqrs, event-driven

When we have to add push updates feature to a system based on CQRS, it seems that make sense let the "read" model to be responsible of manage those push messages. This make a lot of sense when long polling and server events were used (mostly unidirectional)

But WebSockets are bidirectional persistent channels. It is an already established connection that can be used for both get the push updates and send commands. The thing is that the WebSocket connection becomes handy for lot of things like auto-completion search boxes due its reduced latency and statefulness. At first sight, from the technical point of view, there is no justification in using another endpoint (ie: HTTP POST receiver) when there is already a capable channel in place and ready.

Where would be the right place to enable a WebSocket endpoint?

- Read model: It makes sense for push updates for the client and answering queries like auto-completion search boxes, but if it accepts "writes", it would has read and update models in the same place again.
- Update model: It makes sense to accept client inputs. It makes a little sense for send push updates to clients, since they are triggered by other client inputs. But it makes no sense for request-response things like searches for auto-completion searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebSockets are an infrastructure concern. As you point out, they have substantial advantages in some cases over raw HTTP, but they have nothing to do with your domain strategy.

On one of our projects we sent all commands and queries (including observable queries) over WebSockets for the reasons you mention, but this was abstracted away from the authors and clients of those commands.

Setting aside their (slightly) lower latency in modern web stacks [*] I believe there are two obvious places where they can shine

- Subscribing to classic pub/sub streams of events, for instance in a chat system, or as events stream from a user model of some sort.
- Subscribing to "observable read models" or "streaming projections" or "continuous queries" or whatever you'd like to call them, whereby the results of a query (e.g. how many unread messages do I have) is sent to a user whenever it updates.

[*] Some containers like IIS make HTTP calls so expensive you're forced into WebSockets to achieve acceptable latencies (i.e. <1ms). But that is changing.

Comment: So in that project you mentioned how did you end sending commands? through a different channel?

Comment: We sent them through the WebSocket as basic RPC. A custom protocol on the socket allowed multiple commands, queries, and observable queries to be in flight at once.

Comment: Alright, and where did you put the endpoint? in the read model or the update model?

Comment: Ah, we had one endpoint that we launched ourselves (just a self-hosted web socket server). Then APP services were written that called into one or the other. Most commands of course would call into the update model, and most queries would call into the read model. In a way it's like asking whether the HTTP end point for your REST services is in the read model or update model. Neither -- it's infrastructure and you decide how to use it. You'll have calls that do both.